# React state management design pattern new approach thoughts

Tags: react.js, redux, state, mobx

Hey people on the internet!

I do not know where to share my new npm package so I am asking you do you know of a good place to share my package?

Also I would really appreciate if you take a look on it and give me your honest opinion on it [react-spear](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spear)

In short the goal of this package is to make state management more appealing then redux/MobX.
It uses an object of store  that contains Subjects that can subscribe to global value change and synchronize with local state.

I have made an effort to contribute to the developers community with this package and I hope it is a good one.

Please share with me your thoughts

If you have a counter like this:

src/Counter.(jsx/tsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Down } from './Down';
import { Up } from './Up';
import { Display } from './Display';

export const Counter = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Up />
      <Down />
      <Display />
    </div>
  );
};
```

That takes an Up and Down buttons compnent that needs to share their state.
You will have a **store** like this:

src/store.(js/ts)

```
import { Subject } from 'react-spear';

export const Store = {
  counter: new Subject(0),
  // You can add Some other values here to the store,
  // and even an entire Store object to be nested here, whatever you want.
};
```

The Down and Up components should look like this:

src/Up.(jsx/tsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSensable } from 'react-spear';
import { Store } from './store';

export const Up = () => {
  const count = useSensable(Store.counter);
  return <button onClick={() => Store.counter.broadcast(count + 1)}>Up {count}</button>;
};
```

src/Down.(jsx/tsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSensable } from 'react-spear';
import { Store } from './store';

export const Down = () => {
  const count = useSensable(Store.counter);
  return <button onClick={() => Store.counter.broadcast(count - 1)}>Down {count}</button>;
};
```

And the Display component will look loke this:

src/Display.(jsx/tsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSensable } from 'react-spear';
import { Store } from './store';

export const Display = () => {
  const count = useSensable(Store.counter);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Count is {count}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Explanation

- When creating the **store** you are creating a subscribable object that can listen to changes.
- When using the **broadcast** method(*you can help me think other names if you don't like this one*),
  you emit the next value of the state, actualy like setState but globally.
- Then with the **useSensable** hook you are sensing the changes from the store(*listening to broadcast event of that specific subject*).
  Inside it uses ***useState*** to manage the update of the incoming new value,
  and ***useEffect*** to manage subscription to that value.
- So everytime you broadcast a new value every component that consume that value via **useSensable**
  are getting rerendered with the new value.

Hope it make **sense** because it does to me.

## Update

File structure:

```
src
├── hooks
│   └── useSensable.ts
├── lib
│   ├── StorageHandler.ts
│   └── Subscribable.ts
└── subjects
    ├── LocalSubject.ts
    ├── StorageSubject.ts
    ├── SessionSubject.ts
    └── Subject.ts
```

My code from the link above:

src/lib/Subscribable.ts

```
export type SubscribableHandler<T> = (nextValue: T) => void;

export interface ISubscribable<T> {
  subscribe: (handler: SubscribableHandler<T>) => () => void;
}

export class Subscribable<T> implements ISubscribable<T> {
  private _norifiers: SubscribableHandler<T>[] = [];

  protected broadcast(value: T) {
    this._norifiers.forEach((notifier) => notifier(value));
  }

  public subscribe = (handler: SubscribableHandler<T>) => {
    this._norifiers.push(handler);

    return () => {
      this._norifiers = this._norifiers.filter((_) => _ !== handler);
    };
  };
}
```

src/lib/StorageHandler.ts

```
export class StorageHandler {
  private storage: Storage;

  constructor(storage: Storage) {
    this.storage = storage;
  }

  public get<T>(key: string): T {
    const item = this.storage.getItem(key);

    return item ? JSON.parse(item) : null;
  }

  public set<T>(key: string, value: T): void {
    this.storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  public getOrCreate<T>(key: string, defaultValue: T): T {
    let value: T = this.get<T>(key);

    if (value === null) {
      value = defaultValue;
      this.set(key, value);
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

src/subjects/Subject.ts

```
import { ISubscribable, Subscribable } from '../lib/Subscribable';

export interface ISubject<T> extends ISubscribable<T> {
  value: T;
}

export class Subject<T> extends Subscribable<T> implements ISubject<T> {
  public value: T;

  constructor(initialValue?: T) {
    super();
    this.value = initialValue as T;
  }

  public broadcast(nextValue: T) {
    this.value = nextValue;
    super.broadcast(nextValue);
  }
}
```

src/subjects/StorageSubject.ts

```
  
import { StorageHandler } from '../lib/StorageHandler';
import { Subject } from './Subject';

export class StorageSubject<T> extends Subject<T> {
  private storageKey: string;
  private storage: StorageHandler;

  constructor(storage: StorageHandler, storageKey: string, initialValue?: T) {
    super(storage.getOrCreate(storageKey, initialValue));
    this.storageKey = storageKey;
    this.storage = storage;
  }

  public broadcast = (nextValue: T) => {
    this.storage.set(this.storageKey, nextValue);
    super.broadcast(nextValue);
  };
}
```

src/subjects/LocalSubject.ts

```
import { StorageHandler } from '../lib/StorageHandler';
import { StorageSubject } from './StorageSubject';

const localStorageManager = new StorageHandler(localStorage);

export class LocalSubject<T> extends StorageSubject<T> {
  constructor(storageKey: string, initialValue?: T) {
    super(localStorageManager, storageKey, initialValue);
  }
}
```

src/subjects/SessionSubject.ts

```
import { StorageHandler } from '../lib/StorageHandler';
import { StorageSubject } from './StorageSubject';

const sessionStorageManager = new StorageHandler(sessionStorage);

export class SessionSubject<T> extends StorageSubject<T> {
  constructor(storageKey: string, initialValue?: T) {
    super(sessionStorageManager, storageKey, initialValue);
  }
}
```

src/hooks/useSensable:

```
import { ISubject } from '../subjects/Subject';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useSensable = <T>(subject: ISubject<T>) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(subject.value);

  useEffect(() => subject.subscribe(setValue), [subject]);

  return value;
};
```